# I want to output the unique item from specific c++ array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have created a function to count the duplicate items in array .
And everything is fine . but I want to output the unique items only , and this is my problem .

**My function:**

```
void RepeatedCounter(int n){
    int i, j, temp, count= 0;
    int *Numbers = new int[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout << "Enter the number (" << i+1 << "): "; 
        cin >> *(Numbers+i);
    }
    cout << "---------------------\n";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        temp = *(Numbers+i);
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(temp == *(Numbers+j)){
                ++count;
            }
        }
        if(*(Numbers+i+1) != temp)
        cout << *(Numbers+i) << "= " << count << endl;
        count= 0;
    }

    delete []Numbers;
}
```

**Main function:**

```
int Num_Of_Digits= 0;
cout << "How many numbers: ";
cin >> Num_Of_Digits;
RepeatedCounter(Num_Of_Digits);
```

**Example:**

```
Inputs  
1  
5  
3  
5  
1
```

**Wrong result (current output)**

```
1= 2   
5= 2  
3= 1  
5= 2   
1= 2
```

**What I want**

```
1= 2     
5= 2  
3= 1
```

Comment: A frequency table is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @Sander De Dycker: thanks, but I'm still beginner in c++

Comment: If you are beginner then you should learn to do it the right way not the dumb way.

Comment: have a look at @Kerrek SB's answer for an example of how to use a frequency table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    count= 0;
    temp = *(Numbers+i);
    bool found = false;
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(temp == *(Numbers+j)){
            ++count;
        }
    }
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++) {
        if(temp == *(Numbers+j)){
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if(found) continue;
    if(*(Numbers+i+1) != temp)
    cout << *(Numbers+i) << "= " << count << endl;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work, but this time happened another problem.

Comment: The code now works just fine, and this is what I want (You deserve)

Answer (score 4):

This has been done for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>  

int repeated_counter(int n){
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::vector<int> uniques;
    int t;
    for(int i=0; i!=n; ++i)
    {   
        std::cin >> t;
        vec.push_back(t);
    }
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    std::unique_copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
                     std::back_inserter(uniques));

    for(std::vector<int>::iterator it=uniques.begin(); 
        it!=uniques.end(); 
        ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << "=" 
            << std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), *it) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

please refrain from `new`ing memory like you have done it is worse in every way to using a vector.

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/unique_copy.html

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: Are you sure that `unique_copy` doesn't require a *sorted* range?

Comment: @111111: Thanks, but I don't want to use vector,I want other way

Comment: @LionKing why? it is worse in every way, it has absolutely no advantages in this use case.

Comment: @111111: I'm sorry, but I'm still beginner in c++, and I'm still did not understand vector good

Comment: @111111 unique_copy doesn't need a sorted range for it's behavior to be well defined, but it only eliminates _consecutive_ duplicates. If there are duplicates that are not consecutive then those duplicates will be copied into the output range. Sorting is the typical way to guarantee that all duplicate will be consecutive.

Comment: @LionKing using arrays and `new` is IMO more advanced than using `std::vector`

Comment: @bames53 I know that now, that is why it worked on my machine because I didn't put inunique values away from each other, my answer now has a sort.

Comment: @LionKing if you are a beginner then you should learn vector before you learn arrays, arrays basically exist for interoperability with C and a construct to build more complete objects (like a vector)

Comment: @LionKing Sorry if i came across as forceful just half of the question about C++ come from people using the wrong tools for the job, ie an array in this case. If you are learning getting a good book really helps, I can recommend "accelerated C++"

Comment: @111111: Despite the superficial similarities, arrays are actually not used to implement any container, ever. Rather, *allocators* are used to allocate raw memory and construct contained objects in place.

Comment: @KerrekSB thanks: I think i should point out it because of these useful abstractions that I don't actually need to know the exact implementation of the containers. :)

Answer (score 4):

First of: read the user data into a proper dynamic container like a `vector`:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(100);

while (true)
{
    int n;
    std::cout << "Enter the number: ";
    if (!(std::cin >> n)) { break; }
    v.push_back(n);
}
```

Second, make a histogram using a `map`:

```
std::map<int, unsigned int> histogram;
for (int i : v) { ++histogram[i]; }
```

Now output the count:

```
for (auto const & p : histogram)
{
    std::cout << "The number " << p->first
              << " appears " << p->second << " times.\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are only checking against the next number in the list.

```
    if(*(Numbers+i+1) != temp)
    cout << *(Numbers+i) << "= " << count << endl;
```

What you should do is loop over the front on the list (until you get to the number you're on) and check to see if any of those numbers are the same as your current number and only print out if they aren't. You could also check the number before you started the count and not do it if the number has been done already.